# (Do Carmo) Minimum arc length for $\alpha(t)=(t,tsin(\frac{\pi}{t}))$

Tags: geometry, differential, arc-length

the following is an exercise from P. Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" (Ch.1):

9. b) *(A Nonrectifiable Curve)* The following example shows that, with any reasonavle definition, the arc length of a *$C^0$* curve in a closed interval may be unbounded. Let $\alpha:[0,1] \to R^2$ be given as $\alpha(t)=\big(t,t\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{t}\right)\big)$ if $t\neq0$, and $\alpha(0)=(0,0)$. Show, geometrically, that the arc length of the portion of the curve corresponding to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ $\leqslant t \leqslant$ $\frac{1}{n}$ is at least $\frac{1}{2n+1}$.

Use this to show that the length of the curve in the interval $\frac{1}{N}$$\leqslant t\leqslant$$1$ is greater than $$2\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n+1}$$

I'm having trouble answering the first part of this question. My approach has been to determine the lengths between the most convenient points contained within the interval -- i.e. the endpoints of the interval and the critical point, $\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}$.

$$
\begin{split}
\left|\alpha\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)-\alpha\Big(\frac{2}{2n+1}\Big)\right|&+\left|\alpha(2n)-\alpha\Big(\frac{2}{2n+1}\Big)\right|\\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}(n+1)\sqrt{1+4n^2}+n\sqrt{1+4(n+1)^2}
\end{split}
$$

Which is long and intractable. My sense is that there is a more elegant approach. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Between $t_{n+1}={1\over n+1}$ and $t_n={1\over n}$, where $|\sin|=0$,  there is the value $\tau={1\over n+{1\over2}}$, where $|\sin|=1$. It follows that the arc length of $\alpha$ within $[t_{n+1},t_n]$ is
$$\geq|\alpha(t_n)-\alpha(\tau)|+|\alpha(\tau)-\alpha(t_{n+1})|\geq 2|\alpha_2(\tau)|= 2\tau={4\over 2n+1}\ .$$
The sum of these terms is $\infty$.

The $\alpha(2n)$ in your last displayed formula should be replaced by $\alpha\bigl({1\over n+1}\bigr)$, but even then the carrying of the first component $\alpha_1(t)$ along would create computational difficulties.

Comment: Quick question, what is the justification for $|\alpha(t_n)-\alpha(\tau)|+|\alpha(\tau)-\alpha(t_{n+1})|\geq 2|\alpha_2(\tau)|$ ? I just can't quite see it

Comment: @AndrewL: The total length of these two segments is at least two times the $y$-component of these segments, which is $|\alpha_2(\tau)|$.  When $n$ is large this $y$-component is much larger than the $x$-component. Therefore the $x$-component is neglected in the computation.